# Does batch normalization affects the possible solution distribution?

Tags: batch-normalization

As far as I recall, in Deep Learning, batch normalization normalizes each layer activations as a gaussian every batch.  If so, Let $x$ be the input and $z_i$ the activation in the $i$-th layer:  $p(z_i)$ becomes a gaussian with batch-norm. Right?

Does this constraint affects $p(z_i|x)$?